# __globals__ in imported function is much different than __globals__ of function in main module

Tags: python

File **a.py**:

```
def f():
  pass
```

File **main.py**:

```
import a
print("f globals")
print(a.f.__globals__)

def g():
  pass

print("g globals")
print(g.__globals__)
```

`a.f.__globals__` have much more elements than `g.__globals__`. At the first look it seems that built-in functions and types are in `a.f.__globals__`. Why these two dictionaries are different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the module namespaces. The `f()` globals differs from `g()` globals because they both live in different modules.

You'll see the same global namespace if you use [`vars()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) (for globals in `main`) and `vars(a)` (for the globals of module `a`):

```
print(sorted(vars(a).keys() - vars()))
# prints ['__initializing__', 'f'], only `a` has `f` defined, the `__initializing__` value is a flag used by the import machinery
print(sorted(vars().keys() - vars(a)))
# prints ['a', 'g'], only `main` has imported `a` and defined function `g`
```

Each and every module gets its own namespace, `globals()` are not interpreter global, they are module global only. Importing a module means you are importing a reference to that namespace, or creating references to names *in* that namespace.

From the [datamodel documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) on module objects:

> A module object has a namespace implemented by a dictionary object (this is the dictionary referenced by the `__globals__` attribute of functions defined in the module)

and on function objects:

> `__globals__`: A reference to the dictionary that holds the function’s global variables — the global namespace of the module in which the function was defined.

The `__builtins__` key of the main script merely points to the `__builtins__` module, in imported modules that has been expanded into a dictionary. These are the same thing, really.

Comment: I don't know if this really answers why an imported function's `__globals__` should include all of the builtins.

Comment: @Wooble: I showed that there are no more keys in the `f()` globals as there are in the `g()` globals, other than what is to be expected.